# Why doesn't JAXB writes out SWT Widgets?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class to store a list of SWT widgets.

```
@XmlRootElement
class Test {
    private List<Widget> widgets;

    public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }

    public void setWidgets(List<Widget> widgets) {
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }
}
```

I used JAXB to marshall it into XML. However, these widgets are not marshalled.

```
Test t = new Test();
t.setWidgets(widgets);
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
m.marshal(t, System.out);
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test>
    <widgets/>
    <widgets/>
    <widgets/>
</test>
```

Comment: try with xstream http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation can't determine the subclasses of `Widget` using reflection, so you will need to include them when you create your JAXBContext.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class, Button.class, Label.class);
```

Comment: But `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget` is an abstract super class (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FWidget.html), so  your `widgets` property contains subclasses of `Widget`.  Your `JAXBContext` needs to be created in a way so that it is aware of these subclasses.

Comment: i tried putting the actual class inside but it is giving me `IllegalAnnotationExceptions` i think the only way is the define own annotations as mentioned below.. i will try to change my design..

Answer (score 0):

Since the SWT Widget class won't have JAXB annotations, you'll either need to replace that in your class with your own widget details class (that has annotations) or implement an `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` for that property which maps a Widget to your own details class.

You might also want to use

```
    @XmlElement(name = "widget")
```

so you get `<widget>` instead of `<widgets>`

Comment: you mean I need to write all the annotation down in details? SWT consists of many widgets, so I have to "document" them down to be able to parse it?

Comment: @humansg, the SWT widgets don't define their XML mapping, and very rightly so - if they did, someoune would certainly try to serialize them. How do you serialize callbacks?

Comment: @humansg sorry haven't looked at the Widget class so don't know what your best option would be - maybe you can describe in more detail which properties of a widget you want to include in your XML

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) implementations do not require any annotations on the model classes:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan OK have to admit I've lost track of which implementations support which version at the moment :-)  If the OP is able to use a JSR-222 impl I'd be interested to hear how it goes marshalling an SWT widget...

Comment: @MattR - The question has `@XmlRootElement` on the `Test` class so they are using JAXB 2 (JSR-222).  Early versions of JDK 1.6 included a JAXB 2.0 impl, and later versions a JAXB 2.1 impl.  Java SE 7 implementations include a JAXB 2.2 impl.  JAXB 2 impls require atleast Java SE 5.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan thanks, I've learnt something then - just tried this with the impl we're using and it works as long as the parent (root) class is annotated.