# XML mapping with @XmlAnyElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to achieve something like [this](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html).

```
<zoo>
    <lion> ... </lion>
    <dog> ... </dog>
</zoo>
```

I have this class here.

```
public class MainGroup {
    private List<Widget> widgets;

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
        return widgets;
    }
    public void setWidgets(List<Widget> widgets) {
        this.widgets = widgets;
    }
}
```

And this Widget superclass has got subclasses such as Button, Combobox...
I would like to achieve something like this.

```
<MainGroup>
    <Button>...</Button>
    <Combo>...</Combo>
</MainGroup>
```

I am having this exception

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class com.test.Button nor any of its super
  class is known to this context.
```

I tried adding @XmlElementRef but it is still not working.

```
@XmlElementRefs({
     @XmlElementRef(name="Button", type=Button.class),
     @XmlElementRef(name="Combo", type=Combo.class)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am missing quite a lot of things out here.
It seems like I add to add this `@XmlRootElement` annotation to my subclasses of Button and Combo to achieve that.

Can anyone explain to me why I need that annotation in my subclasses... I am confused, I thought an XML would only have a `@XmlRootElement` which in my case should be in `MainGroup` class.

Answer (score 1):

**Mapping your Use Case**

My answer is based on information gathered from one of your related questions:

- [Why doesn't JAXB writes out SWT Widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642254/why-doesnt-jaxb-writes-out-swt-widgets)

Since you are mapping classes for which you do not have the source (and therefore can't add JAXB annotations), I would recommend using the `@XmlElements` mapping.

```
@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name="Button", type=Button.class),
     @XmlElement(name="Combo", type=Combo.class)
})
public List<Widget> getWidgets() {
    return widgets;
}
```

`@XmlElements` corresponds to the XML Schema concept of `xsd:choice`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html

**About `@XmlRootElement`**

> Ok, I am missing quite a lot of things out here. It seems like I add
>   to add this @XmlRootElement annotation to my subclasses of Button and
>   Combo to achieve that.
>
> Can anyone explain to me why I need that annotation in my
>   subclasses... I am confused, I thought an XML would only have a
>   @XmlRootElement which in my case should be in MainGroup class.

`@XmlRootElement` corresponds to global elements in the XML schema, which involves more that just the root element in the document you are unmarshalling.  I'll describe a couple of the roles below:

***`@XmlElementRef`***

`@XmlElementRef` corresponds to the concept of substitution groups.  In an XML Schema you can specify that one global element is substitutable for another.  In JAXB `@XmlRootElement` (and `@XmlElementDecl`) is leveraged to specify global elements:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

***`@XmlAnyElement`***

`@XmlAnyElement` corresponds to the concept of xs:any in XML Schena.  This is part of the document that is pretty free form.  In JAXB when you map a property with `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` it will convert elements matching `@XmlRootElement` declarations into the corresponding domain objects.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: my related post's Widget is from eclipse SWT. while this Widget class here is a self created class and the Button.class and Combo.class is the child class of the Widget class. Which makes `@XmlElementRefs({
     @XmlElementRef(name="Button", type=Button.class),
     @XmlElementRef(name="Combo", type=Combo.class)
})` possible